# Remove bank account details from Woocommerce new order email based on payment method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-method

I have 2 payment methods, bank transfer and credit card. I'm using my local bank account info plugin to display the bank account details and I need to show this bank account details only if they customer select bank transfer (bacs) and not credit card...

Now is showing in both new email order.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This issue is related to the plugin you are using… So contact the authors to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you add description in wrong HOOK, try to use payment method description.

wp-admin->woocommerce->setting->payments->Direct bank transfer
you will see Description

Comment: Hi :) I'm using my local bank account info plugin. The info is all there, bank, account, etc. I'm using woocommerce email customizer, maybe that's the main reason of the problem. Because show its right but in credit card and direct transfer email. And only need it in direct transfer new order email. Thanks.